# Google Maps API-Key in gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

Why don't I have to supply my own gmaps-api-key in [gmaps4rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, you don't need the API key because, [Google Maps Javascript API V3](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/) is used there.

Only Google maps Javascript V2 requires an api-key, and it's deprecated now.

Comment: I know this is an old question . . . but CAN we use an API key with gmaps4rails? I'd like to track my usage and know if I'm getting close to the free API limit.

Comment: FWIW the link in an earlier comment is outdated because it refers to the master branch. An updated link for the v2.0pre branch when this was still applicable is [here](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/v2.0.pre/lib/gmaps4rails/view_helper.rb#L71). The latest version of gmaps4rails does this differently, I believe.

Comment: if anybody still using 1.x version this is the correct link to sourcecode containing `provider_key`: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/1.x/lib/gmaps4rails/view_helper.rb#L69